# Wordpress Error 404 after changing permalink on some pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I’m having a problem since changing my permalinks from default to postname on a wordpress site. I’m getting 404 errors on pages but only the ones that are within the submenu called menus, all the other pages are working fine.

I have been searching on and off for an answer to this for a couple of days now with no success. Someone suggested that it might be an error in the HTaccess file but I don't really know what I'm looking at. I tried generating a new one from Wordpress.org code I found but that just killed the site altogether so I changed it back to the old one. I can see the .htaccess inside the folder public_html there are some others in there with .bak which I assume are from backups I've made of the site. Here is a link to what I'm getting http://www.5thview.com/menus/nibbles/

Not sure why it’s just those pages that are affected other than they are in a submenu. I’ve no idea how to fix this.

I should add that if I switch back to default permalinks it works fine again…

I would need specific instructions if poss as I'm a bit of a newb to the coding side etc although I can find my way around if directed...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: How did you replace the .htaccess? Just from permalinks section? I would suggest making a backup of the current htaccess and then delete it from the server, then go under permalinks section and hit update. It will create a refresh htaccess file. Have you tried that? I'm curious.

Comment: I had tried making a backup of the htaccess and deleting it before but I thought I'd try again as you suggested it. I can't seem to generate a new one. I was told that just by changing the permalink to a different one and pressing save changes, this should generate a new file but it doesn't. When I delete the htaccess the site is not functional at all. The web address produces a 404 error and if I were in permalinks and press save changes the screen just goes white and does nothing.

Comment: When you mentioned the permalinks section, do you mean permalinks manager? I haven't seen that before. I usually go under settings permalinks where you change the type. I tried the permalink manager and pressing update urls (there were none in there to update) and it did the same thing. Screen went white. I'm then forced to replace the old htaccess file to get the site working again...

Comment: Found a fix for my issue. When I looked at the links for the menu/sub item pages the link for all the menu items had been changed to menus rather than menu during the permalink update? Manually fixed all these and now it works! Woop, woop!

Answer (score 0):

The reason links are broken is that your host doesn't have root directive correctly set.

If you are using Nginx, change the virtual host conf file as below:

```
server{
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri$args;
    }
}
```

If your root wordpress is not the webroot but http://[domain.com]/wordpress/:

```
server{
            location /wordpress/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?q=$uri$args;
            }
}
```

Don't forget to restart nginx service.

If you are using Apache, put .htaccess file under your root path, an add below lines

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Don't forget to restart apache service.